# How can I insert into an AVL tree that does not use rotation?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, tree, avl-tree

I want to insert a vector with generic elements into an AVL tree without using rotations, It's possible?

Comment: What do you mean, without using rotations?  Rotations are how you insert things into AVL trees.  (And most other kinds of trees.)

Comment: Exactly, inserting the elements already in the correct position not using rotations because they are already in the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

If the tree is balanced even after insertion of the new element, there is no need for rotation in AVL tree. However, if the tree is not balanced after insertion of new elements, then rotation is required.

That is, if the Balance Factor is not violated after insertion, then rotation of any type is not required and insertion is possible without rotation in this scenario.

Note that balance factor in AVL tree refers to calculation of difference between the height of the left and the right sub-trees and it must not be more than 1 to avoid rotation.